# How to prevent population growth by some means

Tags: biology, apocalypse

The worlds biggest problem is population growth. All that goes in bad way crime, corruption, assassination, robbery, murders everything is at increasing rate in world. And basic reason for all this is population growth. Everyone trying to follow simple rule of life

**Survival of the Fittest**

Result is:
Population increase-> everyone trying to be fittest-> doing crimes to prove/survive that.
So my question is is there any way to stop birth rate completely.
(I am looking for a solution/possibilities in future to find a solution for this... like lets say we have a gas/chemical which if came in air will spread everywhere and all humans will become weaken that they can not commit any crime and also it will make them sterile so no further generation possible).

Comment: Is this a hypothetical or are you looking for some reality? Because many researchers into this sort of thing ten to believe that the population of Earth will plateau at 10 billion or drop fairly drastically after peaking at 10 billion.

Comment: yes i am looking for reality.Actually this is for Countries like China,India where people fight/kill for even sq. inch space of ground....or daily bread and butter...

Comment: Seems like a microbe would be better suited to sterilization than a gas or chemical. It could target reproductive cells. If you want to restart humanity later you could just use sperm from spermbanks to make new babies once a cure for the infection is found, and these babies would not be sterile.

Comment: @user2408578 And where did you learn that people in China or India fight or kill for every a square inch of ground or their food supply? In recent years, it's been shown that India and China's wheat and rice production has soared far, far above their population.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at population trends, in many of the wealthy First World Nations population is static or dropping as people have fewer than the "replacement number" of children. Only the United States is still growing (although rather slowly), while Canada, Western Europe, Russia, Japan Australia are set to have their populations decline (only making up numbers through immigration).

The most dramatic decline is predicted for Russia, where in the worst case scenario they will fall off the demographic cliff and have their population almost halved after 2035.

So in the First world there will be many different problems.

1. Lack of workers. The ratio of workers to retired will become skewed and many of the pension and benefit packages that are currently offered by governments will become unsustainable. Pensioners will continue to vote for their benefits, but eventually workers will revolt against the extreme taxation needed to pay for this (or the extreme devaluation of currency), causing social turmoil within nations.
2. Immigration will no longer seem to be a good thing, since many of the immigrants will come from very different cultures and won't assimilate into the host nation. Europe and Japan are quite particularistic (and if current trends continue in the Middle East, I can see Europeans flipping over and forcing Muslim "guest workers" to leave.) Thirs World nations may also restrict the ability to emigrate, since the brain drain negatively affects them as well.
3. Economic deflation. You think governments are tap dancing fast to try and avoid the debt overhang now? When millions of people world wide are retiring and selling assets, liquidating investments and cashing in retirement accounts, markets are going to crash. There will be more sellers than buyers (and as markets begin to decline, people will panic sell to try and avoid losing their shirts and savings). Houses, vacation properties, stocks and bonds will all be available for a song. On the other hand, there will be a huge amount of cash in circulation as retirees have cashed out to fund their lifestyles, so there will be bubble markets in all kinds of strange places as they rush in to the latest "next big thing" (mostly in health, aging research and odd "nostalgia" related areas).
4. Rinse and repeat. Even in the former third world nations, wealth is rising and the need for large families to assure care in old age is declining now. Third world countries are lowering their birth rates and this demographic decline *may* start to kick in a few decades later (say the 2060's). The world population will gradually shrink into the 22nd century, although there will be lots of bumps and shocks as economies, social institutions and governments have to make drastic changes to the reality of shrinking populations
5. New people at the party. Although the overall population will decline, some demographic subgroups will buck the change. Religious and conservative demographics in the United States generally have above replacement birthrates, while "Liberal" demographics tend to have below replacement birthrates (often choosing not to have children at all). New generations of people with conservative and religious cultural values will gradually outnumber those who do not, also driving changes in poetics and social institutions.

As a famous philosopher once said:

"The world is not only stranger than you imagine, it is stranger than you can imagine".

Comment: What about conutries like China,India where people are fighting/killing each other for one time food....sq. inch ground space....?

Comment: @akzoal The point is that as living standards improve people tend to drop the number of children they have. This has held true in every country studied so far world wide.

Comment: @Tim correct that's the effect after improvement of standard of living....but what about something that is not improved yet->since are stick to traditions..=> they will take time to improve.Lets say 50-50% chance but still land and resources are limited for near future.

Answer (score 3):

## DIRECT ANSWER:

In 1980's China enforced a [mandatory sterilization](http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compulsory_sterilization). After someone has 2 children they had to undergo either birth control or sterilization. More recently, China has enacted a [One-Child policy](http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-child_policy), however ethnic minorities are exempt. There are also **MANY** ways to get around it.

There has also been a lot of [deceit by local administrators](http://maps.unomaha.edu/Peterson/geog1000/Sidebar/ChinaPop.html) who cannot control the people and stop overpopulation. They do this to avoid punishment.

Since these birth control measures have all but failed, my suggestion is that you make conditions so hatch for the common people that they cannot have many kids without fear of extreme punishment. An idea might be a public whipping for both parents followed by their exile. This achieves two purposes:

- A deterrent to having more than 1 child
- One less mouth to feed

Hope this helps your world out.

## ALTERNATE IDEAS

> How to prevent population growth by some mean?

Implies that you are open to any means necessary. The [apocalypse](/questions/tagged/apocalypse) tag implies that you want a society-destroying method. Have the Chinese and Indians deploy military forces to their towns and cities. Since as much as 30 or 40% of the population born is "illegal" give the military orders to kill all illegal citizens. This will **DEFINITELY** spark a rebellion. This will also weaken central authority in the entire region and open up niches for new nations to form and dictators to emerge.

In that event the US would get involved and send in troops (under the support and guise of WHO and NATO, of course) to keep the peace. Russia might not like this and would follow suit...

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to introduce sterilizing chemicals into the water supply. Rich people or people in the know could stick to bottled water for a while but the rest of the population would get sterilized. The problem with this method is that it requires a fair amount of infrastructure and co-operation from different people who would be able to blow the whistle. It would also only affect one country unless other countries joined in, which again would make the conspiracy harder to keep quiet.

A more technological answer would be to genetically engineer a virus that looks and acts like the flu, but sterilizes anyone that it infects. Spread that virus from multiple hotspots around the globe (for example major hub airports) and it would infect most of the population. Vaccinations can be arranged ahead of time and given to anyone you wish to spare.

One big problem with these ideas though is that while sterilization seems more humane on the surface since you are not actually killing anyone - the long term effects would be drastic. If the population drops too much too fast then the rapidly aging population would have no-one to support them. The results would be a lot of old people starving or freezing to death with hardly anyone to look after them or keep the infrastructure running.

Answer (score 0):

1. Engineer a biological virus that sterilises people. (makes them
   infertile)
2. Make sure that the virus is not 100% effective (ie: some percentage
   of humans are fertile post infection)
3. Put it in the water supply

twist: the virus mutates...

Answer (score -1):

One way would be fore political leaders to purposely fabricate a reason to declare war thereby killing off a large portion of the population through these means.

You also have genocide as an option.

Others have mention sterilization.